# Autorotation in UINavigationController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, orientation, autorotate

There're an **UINavigationController** with **rootViewController** (as root) and **secondViewController** (as a child). The **rootViewController** should be able to rotate to any orientation (that works as expected, I just override the *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation*), but the **secondViewController** should work in Portrait mode only (here, I set the *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation* to

```
interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
```

The issue: after navigating to the **secondViewController** from the **rootViewController** ***while in landscape***, the **secondViewController** doesn't switch its UI back to portrait. Is there a right way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a

```
[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
```

After your declaration there.  See if that works.